# Grab the latest record if effectivedate is the same with other rows

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to grab all rows for a specified `RowID` where `EffectiveDate` is different. 
However, if we have multiple rows with the same `EffectiveDate`, I would like to grab all other rows and the last record inserted using `InsertDateTime` column for the dates that are the same.

Here is the sample data:

[image]

So in this example, the output I'm looking for is this:

[image]

We are skipping the rows with ID's 2 && 3 since their `InsertDateTime` is smaller than the `InsertDateTime` for row ID 4.

The approach I'm taking is to do a a `datediff`between the `EffectiveDate` and if the `second` is `0` than they are the same values and I should grab the last record.  However, with this approach it's not returning my last record because of my `join`.

I think I'm complicating this query.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
  ID int identity(1,1),
  RowID char(10),
  EffectiveDate DateTime,
  InsertDateTime DateTime
)

INSERT INTO #MyTable(RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDatetime) VALUES 
('55555', '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000','2017-06-01 13:19:01.000')
INSERT INTO #MyTable(RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDatetime) VALUES 
('55555', '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000','2017-06-01 13:34:01.000')
INSERT INTO #MyTable(RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDatetime) VALUES 
('55555', '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000','2017-06-01 13:54:01.000')
INSERT INTO #MyTable(RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDatetime) VALUES 
('55555', '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000','2017-06-01 13:56:01.000')

--The correct output it should return
--SELECT * FROM #MyTAble WHERE ID IN (1,4) order by 4

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT ID, RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDateTime,
  ROW_Number() OVER (Order by InsertDateTime) AS rn
  FROM #MyTable
),
CTE2 AS
(
  SELECT datediff(second, mc.EffectiveDate, mp.EffectiveDate) as Sec, mc.*, 
  mp.EffectiveDate as Date2 FROM CTE mc 
  JOIN CTE mp
  ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
 )
 SELECT *, CASE WHEN SEC = 0 THEN 1
 ELSE 0 END AS Valid
 FROM CTE2
```

[Stack Exchange Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/679780/grab-the-latest-record-if-effectivedate-is-the-same)

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Will the last ID always be the latest IsertDateTime? If so, can you use UNIQUE and ORDER BY in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your query by adding EffetiveDate to ROW_NUMBER partition and ordering by RowID, EffectiveDate and InsertDateTime DESC

> ```
> ;WITH CTE AS
> (
>   SELECT ID, RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDateTime,
>          ROW_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY RowID, EffectiveDate ORDER BY RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDatetime DESC) AS rn
>   FROM   #MyTable
> )
> SELECT *
> FROM   CTE
> WHERE  rn = 1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | RowID      | EffectiveDate       | InsertDateTime      | rn
> -: | :--------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :-
>  1 | 55555      | 01/06/2017 00:00:00 | 01/06/2017 13:19:01 | 1 
>  4 | 55555      | 01/07/2017 00:00:00 | 01/06/2017 13:56:01 | 1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0e728f78ea89dc186e00c94830585f1a)*

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over complicating things. Just partition you `row_number` call by `RowID` and `EffectiveDate`, order it by `InsertDatetime` and select the rows with `rn = 1`:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ID, RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDateTime,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RowID, EffectiveDate ORDER BY InsertDatetime DESC) AS rn
  FROM #MyTable
)
SELECT ID, RowID, EffectiveDate, InsertDateTime
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**[Stack Exchange Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/679812/grab-the-latest-record-if-effectivedate-is-the-same)**